# Does the Alchemist's Lab provide "alchemical equipment" in the sense of Craft (Alchemy)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, alchemy

So I am a little confused by the Core Rules Books definition of Craft (Alchemy);

> To make an item using Craft(alchemy), you must have alchemical
>   equipment. If you are working in a city, you can buy what you need as
>   part of the raw materials cost to make the item, but alchemical
>   equipment is difficult or impossible to come by in some places.
>   Purchasing and maintaining an alchemist's lab grants a +2 circumstance
>   bonus on craft(alchemy) checks because you have the perfect tools for
>   the job.

If you have the [Alchemist's Lab](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Alchemist-s-Lab) can you assume you "have alchemical equipment" already? So alchemical equipment wouldn't need to be sold in that area for you to craft items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Lab description (find it [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances)) says:

> This lab is used for making alchemical items, and provides a +2 circumstance bonus on Craft (alchemy) checks. It has no bearing on the costs related to the Craft (alchemy) skill. Without this lab, a character with the Craft (alchemy) skill is assumed to have enough tools to use the skill but not enough to get the +2 bonus that the lab provides.

So yes, even without common sense *laboratory = equipment*, description of what lab is ensures that it is in fact sufficient, and that it not only allows you to use alchemy, but also gives you bonus.

Equipment parts and supplies that gets used up / damaged regularly, like oil for heaters, charcoal in filters etc is included in material cost of alchemical creations already. Treat them as raw materials, because complicated, hard to get by things are made to last. And for other things like broken vials and flasks - we don't care for nicks on swords, we ignore minor damage on armor, why would we care for minor wear on lab?

Comment: Hi Molot, thanks for the reply, I had read the labs description. It still did not really give me an absolute answer however as it states; you will have enough equipment with or without the lab. suggesting perhaps you will need to "purchase" the required equipment with the raw materials either way. Anyway I am inclined to agree it will count as equipment as that seems to be common sense.

Comment: @bennyboy Equipment that gets used up is included in material cost of alchemical creations already. And for other things like broken vials - we don't care for nicks on swords, we ignore minor damage on armor, why would we care for minor wear on lab?

Comment: All good points.